# Bad Request when using Substitutions with the SendGrid API v3 via the Python API Wrapper

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I created a nice template via the SendGrid UI and am encountering issues trying to send emails with it via the sendgrid python API wrapper (v5.4.1). I've got the template id for a template that has the following (truncated) text:

> Hello, {{name}}!
>
> Click the following link to verify your account: {{verification_url}}.

However, when following the [example in the documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/use_cases/transational_templates.md), I get a 400 Bad Request error whenever I include the personalizations. I am including the personalizations as follows:

```
mail.personalizations[0].add_substitution(Substitution("{{name}}", "Example User"))
```

In addition, `mail.get()` returns the following:

```
{
  'from': {
    'email': 'test@school.edu'
  },
 'subject': 'Account Verification',
 'personalizations': 
    [
      {
        'to': [{'email': 'testemail@test.com'}],
        'substitutions': {
                          '{{name}}': 'Example User'}
                         }
    ],
 'template_id': '<template_id_here>'
}
```

Is there any way to debug what's going on? A 400 Bad Request unfortunately isn't all that helpful...

It looks like these features are actually not yet supported: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a couple of weeks ago as well. The format for substitutions has been changed to use dynamic_template_data.

Instead of:

```
    mail.personalizations[0].add_substitution(Substitution("{{name}}", "Example User"))
```

Use:

```
    mail.personalizations[0].dynamic_template_data = Substitution("name", "Example User").get()
```

The get() returns a JSON ready version of the substitution. Additionally make sure that you're using at least version 5.6.0 of the Sendgrid API. This feature was just added, here's a link to the github commit: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/commit/4be8d580ec15f1f10180a562aeace8478f76597e

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent change from API V3, this works for me

`import os
import sendgrid
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email, Personalization`

```
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    mail = Mail()
    mail.from_email = Email('customerservice@jafutexpress.com.ng')
    mail.subject = "You are welcome!"
    mail.template_id = 'template_id'
    p = Personalization()
    p.add_to(Email('test@example.com'))
    p.dynamic_template_data = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    }
    mail.add_personalization(p)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.body)
```